# IndexError: string index out of range - Python

Tags: python

Im getting this error.

```
mac_decrypt+=decrypt_datei[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I tried everything but no success. Can someone help me pls, where I do mistake!

Here is Code:

```py
lauf = len(decrypt_datei) - 1
nachricht_decrypt = ''
nachricht_length = ord(decrypt_datei[lauf])
nachricht_length = len(decrypt_datei) - (nachricht_length + 1)
lauf -= 1
while nachricht_length <= lauf:
    nachricht_decrypt += decrypt_datei[nachricht_length]
    nachricht_length += 1
print('entschluesselung fertig!')
print('mac Ueberpruefung:')

while s == False:
    # Mac UeberprUefen/ Nachricht zeigen
    macpassword_try = raw_input('Geben Sie den Macpassword:')
    hash_macpassword_try = hashlib.sha512(macpassword_try).hexdigest()

    lauf = ord(decrypt_datei[0])
    mac_decrypt = ''
    i = 1
    while i <= lauf:
        mac_decrypt += decrypt_datei[i]
        i += 1
```

Comment: can you print the variables   **lauf**  and    **decrypt_datei**  ?  print it before the line _while i <= lauf_

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies in:

`lauf = ord(decrypt_datei[0])`

`ord` returns an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character.

If you would have `ord('a')` that would return `97` thus if your string `decrypt_datei` contains `'a'` and `len(decrypt_datei)` is smaller than `97` it will result in `string index out of range`

I suspect logical error here.

Comment: It is also good to point that the line in question is `lauf = ord(decrypt_datei[0])`.